# Chart.JS - updating Labels from Chart 0 also updated Labels from Chart 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I have two line chart. I want to update the data for both of them, but somehow, after I update only the first Chart, the Label data on the 2nd Chart is also udpated at the same time. Am i Doing Something Wrong?

As shown in the image, i do print both label Chart 0 and 1, at first it was as expected. But After i do insert new label data to chart 0 using  `chartRpm[0].data.labels.push(0);` the label on chart 1 also is inserted with the new label
[image]

sc

```
console.log("CHART 0 LABELS");
console.log(chartRpm[0].data.labels);

console.log("CHART 1 LABELS");
console.log(chartRpm[1].data.labels);

chartRpm[0].data.labels.push(0);

console.log("CHART 0 LABELS");
console.log(chartRpm[0].data.labels);

console.log("CHART 1 LABELS");
console.log(chartRpm[1].data.labels);
```

Comment: You need to mention chart method with parameters that you are using. without that can't get an idea.

Comment: @Dipten they do use the same config variable, i guess thats what causing it. I set 2 different variable for the label now, and its working, thx for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `chartRpm[0].data.labels` and `chartRpm[1].data.labels` point to the same reference, how do you define `chartRpm`?

Comment: It Does!! it worked finally, when i set 2 different reference for the Label, THX for the answer

Comment: Glad that I could be of help, since I had the same problem when getting started.